# How to extract the parameter value from the url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets

```
response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/cse/welcome.html?first=fname&last=lname&dname=dept&mname=mobno");
```

How to extract the first,last,dname,mname parameters from the Url and I want to use those extracted values in my redirected html document(welcmoe.html). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The four variables from the java servlet can be hardcoded and passed as a string like this

```
StringBuilder url =new StringBuilder();
url.append("http://localhost:8080/cse/welcome.html");
url.append("?first="+fname);
url.append("&last="+lname);
url.append("&dname="+dept);
url.append("&mname="+mobno);
String URL=url.toString();
String urlEncoded=response.encodeRedirectURL(URL);
response.sendRedirect(urlEncoded);
```

Then these variables can be obtained and called in the javascript in this way

```
<script>
function getParameterByName(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
results = regex.exec(location.search);
return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
var fname = getParameterByName('first');
var lname=getParameterByName('last');
var dept=getParameterByName('dname');
var mobno=getParameterByName('mname');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted client side using JS, you could do the following.

```
//Create an array from query strings
//such as ['first=fname', 'last=lname', ...]
var querystring = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
var props = {};
//Loop thru the array
querystring.forEach(function(item) {
    //split each item
    var item = item.split("=");
    //set the first part as key and last/second part as value
    props[item.shift()] = item.pop();
});
alert ("first: " + props["first"]);
alert ("last: " + props["last"]);
//and so on...
```

Comment: `response.sendRedirect("localhost:8080/cse/…);`                                   I got that worked but the paramaters(fname, lname,dept and mobno) which has been passed in the url has been passed as a value and not as a paramer... how can I pass the parameter in the url in the sendRedirect() method? @ shetty